# Why do browsers allow onmousedown JS to change href?

Tags: javascript, security, href, phishing

I've noticed for a very long time that when you try to copy a link location or open a link on Facebook, it modifies the link and passes it through `l.php`.

For example, I can be sent to

```
 http://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&h=DKVUritNDJDJLDLVbldoDLFKBLOD5dlfDJY_-d3fgDUaA9b
```

even though my browser render the link preview as `http://www.google.com/`.

Today, I took a closer look using Firebug and found that Facebook puts `onmousedown="UntrustedLink.bootstrap($(this)[...]` in the `<a>` tag. The second I right clicked the link, I saw the `href` attribute change in Firebug.

This worries me.

The advice many of us have given to less tech-savvy people (check where the link is taking you before you click so that you don't become a victim of phishing) now seems to have become useless. Isn't this a security risk? Can't phishing websites misuse this?

Why don't browsers prevent this behavior either by disallowing `onmousedown` to change the `href` or by running the javascript before reading the `href` attribute, so that I am sent to the location I thought I going to, not the one change while I was clicking it?

**Edit**: I want to briefly emphasize that what bothers me more than the risk of phishing is that users are being misled and it simply feels wrong to me that this can happen, whether by a trusted source or not.

Comment: Having a limitation like this one will not solve anything.

Comment: Onmousedown link changing is an incredibly annoying behavior as it makes it complicated to quickly paste links. That said, outgoing click tracking is important, so maybe the better solution would be if browsers supported a more transparent method of hijacking clicks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree that there is potential here for phishing. This was reported as a [bug in FireFox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=229050) quite a long time ago, but the problem is this:

```
<body onmousedown="document.getElementById('changeMe').href='www.somewhereelse.com'">
    <a id="changeMe" href="www.google.com">google</a>
</body>
```

Events bubble up to their parent, you would need to detect if an onmousedown event was going to change the href of a child element. Sounds reasonable? Okay, how about this:

```
<script>
    function switcher() {
       window.location = "www.somewhereelse.com";
       return false;
    }
</script>
<body onmousedown="switcher()">
    <a href="www.google.com">google</a>
</body>
```

So we need to look out for `window.location` in functions triggered by onmousedown events as well. Still sound reasonable? How about if I have the onmousedown event remove the link altogether, replace it with a new element and then trigger the click on that. I can keep coming up with examples.

The point is, Javascript can be used to misdirect people using the status bar - you shouldn't trust it, you can only trust the URL.

To change this browsers would need to give the set href value on a link at the time of the click presidency over any other events that might happen, basically disable mouse events on anchor tags. I would venture to guess they probably won't do this, it would break too many applications that already exist.

**Edit:** Alternatively, I've seen people propose different methods of detecting and warning the user about possible link hijacking, but I've not seen any implemented yet.

Comment: Just to understand this a little better and to get your view on this: Is it possible, then, for a browser to delay mouse actions, until after the navigation has happened? That will mean that if the link is within the page (e.g. `href="#foo"`) the JS will still work (browsers could indicate this in the url preview), but if the link actually points to a different page, you are sent to the page that you actually think you are going to. If, as Tgr suggested, browsers transparently told the website where you are going, browsers could let you know that the site is being told using a small icon.

Comment: To rephrase your approach: First let the navigation happen based on the href value of the link when you clicked it, then execute Javascript event and let the user know with an icon that a Javascript event is going to be delayed by the navigation. The problem I see is: what if the event was meant to stop the navigation?

Comment: I have more thoughts I can't fit in the comments, should we move to a chat?

Comment: Sure. I haven't used it before. Do you make a new chat room or use an existing on like JS?

Comment: While I haven't been able to get onto chat, it seems like there is no simple answer to my question. If you could post links/brief summaries to those different methods, that would be terrific. I was hoping for an answer that both (a) explained why there is no simple solution and (b) shared a thought for the future: are links always going to be like this or is there anything that we can look forward to? I think your answer was almost there. I am accepting it anyway, although, like I said before, a link or an explanation of those ideas you mentioned would be great.

Answer (score 3):

> The advice many of us have given to less tech-savvy people (check where the link is taking you before you click so that you don't become a victim of phishing) now seems to have become useless.

If by "check" you mean the link 'preview' browsers show at the bottom status bar then you are correct. That is not enough to check whether a link really goes where it claims to be going. For instance, running the jquery script below on a page will cause all link to go to google.com regardless of what the actual href target of the link is:

```
$('a').click(function(evt){evt.preventDefault();window.location.href="http://google.com"})
```

Answer (score 2):

> Can't phishing websites misuse this?

Not really, because facebook is where the said javascript would have to be called from. The user has to go an untrusted source in the first place who would embed the javascript in the  tag.

Comment: Even *trusted* sites can fall victim to vulnerabilities that would allow an attacker to inject code like this.

Comment: If a 'trusted site' were to be vulnerable to XSS, I'm sure the aforementioned vulnerability would be the last thing an attacker would want to exploit.